# Function with given properties

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, roots

Consider the following function:

$$g(x)=\sin²(πx)+f(x)$$

We have to construct a "non trivial" function $f(x)$ such that $g(x)$ doesn't have any (real or complex) roots in the region $\{x|Re(x)>c \textrm{, for some constant c}\}$. Also, $|f(x)|<M$, for $x > c, x \in \mathbb{R}$.

> We have to find/construct a class of function $f(x)$ with above given properties.

Examples are also welcome.

"Non trivial" means a function not of the type $f(x)=h(x)-\sin^2(πx)$ where $h(x)$ is a function with no roots (neither complex nor real).

Comment: What about a function of the type $f(x)=xh(x)-\sin^2(\pi x)$ where $h(x)$ is a function with no roots? or $f(x)=x(x-i)(x+i)h(x)-\sin^2(\pi x)$? Do you require $g(x)$ to have infinitely many roots? Because if not, there are all kinds of examples of this type.

Comment: @GregMartin sorry sir, but I can't understand what you are saying. $xh(x)=h_1(x)$ is still a function with no roots for $Re(x)>0$ and similar otherwise.